# Why does an implicit conversion operator from <T> to <U> accept <T?>?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, implicit-conversion, value-type

This is a weird behaviour that I cannot make sense of. In my example I have a class `Sample<T>` and an implicit conversion operator from `T` to `Sample<T>`.

```
private class Sample<T>
{
   public readonly T Value;

   public Sample(T value)
   {
      Value = value;
   }

   public static implicit operator Sample<T>(T value) => new Sample<T>(value);
}
```

The problem occurs when using a nullable value type for `T` such as `int?`.

```
{
   int? a = 3;
   Sample<int> sampleA = a;
}
```

**Here is the key part:**
In my opinion this should not compile because `Sample<int>` defines a conversion from `int` to `Sample<int>` but not from `int?` to `Sample<int>`. **But it compiles and runs successfully!** (By which I mean the conversion operator is invoked and `3` will be assigned to the `readonly` field.)

And it gets even worse. Here the conversion operator isn't invoked and `sampleB` will be set to `null`:

```
{
   int? b = null;
   Sample<int> sampleB = b;
}
```

A great answer would probably be split into two parts:

1. Why does the code in the first snippet compile?
2. Can I prevent the code from compiling in this scenario?

Comment: [Here there is the documentation about C# conversions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/conversions.md#user-defined-conversions)... But I can't find which bullet point does what is happening here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can take a look at how compiler lowers this code:

```
int? a = 3;
Sample<int> sampleA = a;
```

into [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgNQMwIExwDKAhgLYAOANgKYA8AKgHwYDeGcHOcATtccAHsAdpQCecenABqxSgFdqaTOg4JcJCjQAUkgG6yFASnYc2K1RxnzqcALxx91paoC+GE2oSIAbHACWmn4Axn4ALnAC5NTcxKEC3ERkVHRMOg4G1IZ2jHBC1ADuiZopjFqORkpuylxQBADCcGYWNQAscACyWllNFqoevX5CoQD8cMR2cNjOvRwaybSDoTkAzkk0AIITxNMcVS5AA=):

```
int? nullable = 3;
int? nullable2 = nullable;
Sample<int> sample = nullable2.HasValue ? ((Sample<int>)nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) : null;
```

Because `Sample<int>` is a class its instance can be assigned a null value and with such an implicit operator the underlying type of a nullable object can also be assigned. So assignments like these are valid:

```
int? a = 3;
int? b = null;
Sample<int> sampleA = a; 
Sample<int> sampleB = b;
```

If `Sample<int>` would be a `struct`, that of course would give an error.

**EDIT:**
So why is this possible? I couldn't find it in spec because it's a deliberate spec violation and this is only kept for backwards compatibility. You can read about it in [code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1159a17a7a25737e56c5aac38ed26efd93c41bec/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LocalRewriter/LocalRewriter_Conversion.cs#L1058):

> DELIBERATE SPEC VIOLATION:
>   The native compiler allows for a "lifted" conversion even when the return type of the conversion not a non-nullable value type. For example, if we have a conversion from struct S to string, then a "lifted" conversion from S? to string is considered by the native compiler to exist, with the semantics of "s.HasValue ? (string)s.Value : (string)null".  The Roslyn compiler perpetuates this error for the sake of backwards compatibility.

That's how this "error" is [implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1159a17a7a25737e56c5aac38ed26efd93c41bec/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LocalRewriter/LocalRewriter_Conversion.cs#L1080) in Roslyn:

> Otherwise, if the return type of the conversion is a nullable value type, reference type or pointer type P, then we lower this as:
>
> ```
> temp = operand
> temp.HasValue ? op_Whatever(temp.GetValueOrDefault()) : default(P)
> ```

So according to [spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/conversions.md#lifted-conversion-operators) for a given user-defined conversion operator  `T -> U` there exists a lifted operator `T? -> U?` where `T` and `U` are non-nullable value types. However such logic is also implemented for a conversion operator where `U` is a reference type because of the above reason.

**PART 2** How to prevent the code from compiling in this scenario? Well there is a way. You can define an additional implicit operator specifically for a nullable type and decorate it with an attribute `Obsolete`. That would require the type parameter `T` to be restricted to `struct`:

```
public class Sample<T> where T : struct
{
    ...

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static implicit operator Sample<T>(T? value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This operator will be chosen as a first conversion operator for nullable type because it's more specific.

If you can't make such a restriction you must define each operator for each value type separately (if you are *really* determined you can take advantage of reflection and generating code using templates):

```
[Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
public static implicit operator Sample<T>(int? value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

That would give an error if referenced in any place in code:

> Error CS0619  'Sample.implicit operator Sample(int?)' is obsolete: 'Some error message'

Comment: You should bold the last sentence (`If... struct`)... It is the response to "question 2"

Comment: My 5 cents here. Try the example above with Expressions, and you'll end up with "System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value". Basically in a normal code c# compiler does a lifted conversion, but for expression trees it throws an exception.

Answer (score 20):

I think it's lifted conversion operator in action. Specification says that:

> Given a user-defined conversion operator that converts from a
>   non-nullable value type S to a non-nullable value type T, a lifted
>   conversion operator exists that converts from S? to T?. This lifted
>   conversion operator performs an unwrapping from S? to S followed by
>   the user-defined conversion from S to T followed by a wrapping from T
>   to T?, except that a null valued S? converts directly to a null valued
>   T?.

It looks like it's not applicable here, because while type `S` is value type here (`int`), type `T` is not value type (`Sample` class). However [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4555) in Roslyn repository states that it's actually a bug in specification. And Roslyn [code](https://github.com/gafter/roslyn/blob/e43b45175c99cfe2391c7c939cae873637117cff/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Semantics/Conversions/UserDefinedImplicitConversions.cs) documentation confirms this:

> As mentioned above, here we diverge from the specification, in two
>   ways. First, we only check for the lifted form if the normal form was
>   inapplicable. Second, we are supposed to apply lifting semantics only
>   if the conversion  parameter and return types are *both* non-nullable
>   value types.
>
> In fact the native compiler determines whether to check for a lifted
>   form on the basis of:
>
> - Is the type we are ultimately converting from a nullable value type?
> - Is the parameter type of the conversion a non-nullable value type?
> - Is the type we are ultimately converting to a nullable value type, pointer type, or reference type?
>
> If the answer to all those questions is "yes" then we lift to nullable
>   and see if the resulting operator is applicable.

If compiler would follow specification - it would produce a error in this case as you expect (and in some older versions it did), but now it does not.

So to summarize: I think compiler uses lifted form of your implicit operator, which should be impossible according to specification, but compiler diverges from specification here, because:

- It is considered bug in specification, not in compiler.
- Specification was already violated by old, pre-roslyn compiler, and it's good to maintain backwards compatibility.

As described in first quote describing how lifted operator works (with addition that we allow `T` to be reference type) - you may note it describes exactly what happens in your case. `null` valued `S` (`int?`) is assigned directly to `T` (`Sample`) without conversion operator, and non-null is unwrapped to `int` and run through your operator (wrapping to `T?` is obviously not needed if `T` is reference type).

Comment: This explains why I wasn't able to infer what was happening from the specification :-) [Comment about this on github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4344#issuecomment-130918048): *Does that mean that regarding the snippet above (from a non-nullable value type S to a reference type T) the old compiler's behaviour S? -> T (or S? -> S -> T) was actually undefined behaviour?* and response: *@yaakov-h No, it wasn't undefined. It was well defined as requiring a compile-time error. We're going to change the language specification and the Roslyn compiler to make this behave as before.*

Comment: Could we summarize your answer as follows?: The Roslyn documentation diverges from the C# specification on purpose. And that in turn (possibly) causes the undesired behaviour. And we cannot expect that this will be fixed because the decision was made on purpose.

Comment: @NoelWidmer basically yes, though as stated in linked issue - it is considered bug in specification ("Of course this is a bug in the spec") and for that reason the only necessary fix is a fix in specification, not in compiler.

Answer (score 8):

> Why does the code in the first snippet compile?

A code sample from a source code of `Nullable<T>` that can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs):

```
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value) {
    return value.Value;
}

[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue) {
    return hasValue ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

The struct `Nullable<int>` has an overriden explicit operator as well as method `GetValueOrDefault` one of these two is used by compiler to convert `int?` to `T`.

After that it runs the `implicit operator Sample<T>(T value)`.

A rough picture of what happens is this:

```
Sample<int> sampleA = (Sample<int>)(int)a;
```

If we print `typeof(T)` inside of `Sample<T>` implicit operator it will display: `System.Int32`.

In your second scenario compiler doesn't use the `implicit operator Sample<T>` and simply assigns `null` to `sampleB`.

Comment: *The struct Nullable<int> has an overriden implicit operator that implicitly converts int? to int* What? `int a = (int?)5` doesn't work.

Comment: That is called *explicit*, not *implicit*.

Comment: There's no sign of this implicit conversion in the compiled IL. Just a test against `System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_HasValue` that controls branching behaviour. See https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/653b1be91e0571613377191b6e9f6366

Comment: ...this implies that the compiler has special handling of nullables, and this behaviour is *not* implemented as an implicit operator in `Nullable<T>`

Comment: @spender Afaik nullable value types do have special meaning to the compiler. Since the designers tried to mix `null` and value types they probably had some corner cases that were not very well discussed (or no good solutions could be found) and one in turn ended up to be this "feature" that implicitly causes errors. I don't think this is the desired behaviour but probably the result of some type system issue they tried to solve.